# Return value, if blank then return value of another cell if another cell is blank then return value from third cell

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

If Cherry has value then keep it and delete/hide the other ones in that row, from picture the red ones should be deleted/hidden and the black ones should be keept. Obs in reality there is no color difference this is only for explenation. so in this case data cell D2 is staying and data on C2,B2 and A2 are removing/hiding. And if the data on D2 whas missing then C2 under would be staying, B2 and A2 whas removing/hiding and so on... if only Apple have data for some cell like A23 then that will be staying and not removed/hide, and of course B23,C23 and D23 would in that case be empty **How can I implement this logic in VBA or Excel formula?, Thanks!**]

[image: Excel sheet]

Comment: First, please provide some code, that you have tried. Second, your description is unclear, maybe you should use cell adress, for example "cell C2" instead of "p under Orange".

Comment: let me rephrase your request: whenever a cell is not empty, you want all the cells to the left of that cell and on the same line to be emptied. Is this correct?

Comment: @L.Dutch YES, that is correct, thanks!

Comment: @Limak now it's fixed like you wished, if I had a code...but I dont, I am totally stuck on this. I am also VBA, Excel newbie.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work. Hope that it wasn't your homework ;)

```
Sub ThisMacro()
    Dim LastRow As Long, LastCol As Long
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    For i = 2 To LastRow
        LastCol = Cells(i, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
        If LastCol > 1 Then
            Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, LastCol - 1)).ClearContents
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: as an consultant you always have homework, sometimes you can solve it by your self and sometimes you just need some good help ;  ) Thanks a lot!

Comment: one more question, what if A,B,C,D is actually P,Q,R,S and you do still have columns from A.... i.e there is more columns that cannot be deleted, How is code code going to be change in taht case in orde to not delete data from other columns that isnt in this range?

Comment: Ok, note that the `LastRow` is based on last non-blank cell i column A. If e.g. column A has last value in row 90, and column B in row 110, this macro will clear values only till reach row 90.

Comment: Ok, but I'm asking about the columns actually. from right to left deleting not the row part. since I want this logic to work only on columns P,Q,R and S I dont want to affect columns before thise i.e A to O, how can I limit this to only affect P to S?

Comment: You can edit `Range(Cells(i, 1), Cells(i, LastCol - 1)).ClearContents`, and change first coulmn to the one that you want, example `Range(Cells(i, 16), Cells(i, LastCol - 1)).ClearContents`. You than have to change condition on `If LastCol > 1 Then`, too.